# UrlRewriting parameters in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have an url like https://www.demo.com?p1=10&p2=20.

My problem is I want to urlrewriting like https://www.demo.com/page1?p1=10&p2=20

However I cannot match url pattern for p1 and p2 parameters. For that reason I cannot convert url to https://www.demo.com/page1?p1=10&p2=20

Comment: Why is it a problem? What did you try to fix it? How did it not fix it?

Comment: Could you provide your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I couldnt write match url in web.config. I tried write that "^page1?p1=([0-9a-z)+]&p2=([0-9a-z)+]" to match url part but unfortunately "&" icon gave error